Как передавать дополнительные параметры в AJAX запросе php
Всем привет, пишу тех задание для собеса, столкнулся с тем, что не могу передавать дополнительные параметры в handler.php

Пишу такой запрос, как мне передать туда еще один кастомный параметр key: $arResult['APIKEY'], чтоб я мог использовать его в обработчике?

Тут есть несколько примеров: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539502/this-serialize-how-to-add-a-value

Ваш код вряд ли полный, откуда вообще вы взяли $arResult['APIKEY']??? Код лучше добавлять в вопрос, а не в скриншот.

Стандартный способ для передачи дополнительных параметров - добавить невидимый инпут в форму:
<form id="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="APIKEY" value="<?=$arResult['APIKEY']?>">
...

